# What could cause .NET remoting to fail but only if message sent from code running in IIS?

Tags: c#, iis, remoting

Have an app that uses Remoting over a tcp channel to send message from web app (the client) to a central server.

```
TcpClientChannel channel = new TcpClientChannel();
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, true);
IPC message = (IPC)Activator.GetObject(typeof(IPC), remotingUrl);                
// IPC is class that is being 'remoted'
message.SomeMethod(....);
```

For most part this works fine but on one particular set of web servers it errors on .SomeMethod with :-

> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed. at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult) at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.AuthenticateAsClient(NetworkCredential credential, String targetName, ProtectionLevel requiredProtectionLevel, TokenImpersonationLevel allowedImpersonationLevel) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.CreateAuthenticatedStream(Stream netStream, String machinePortAndSid

Of course according to IT Ops there are no differences between the server that works, and the one that doesn't...

There are no hardware or software firewalls between/on the sending (client) web server and the receiving server.

I've put the same code in a console app and it works just fine when running on the problematic sending server (even when running under the app pool account).

Therefore I conclude that this only fails when the sending code ran in the context of IIS on some of the servers.

Any idea of which settings (perhaps aspnet.config or web.config or IIS Metabase) or anything else that could cause this.

Key parts

- works when sending from web app on some servers fails on some others
- on those servers that fail it works fine when running as console app
- problem *has* to be on the sending side

*(One more key part for anyone googling that error message - like I haven't done that ;) - the secure channel setting is the same on receiving and sending servers).*

Comment: Have you checked that the app in IIS is configured to use an application pool configured as a network/domain user?

Comment: Also test to put your Application Pool user as local administrator. If that works, it has to do with security settings of some sort on the server.

Comment: Have ran cmd line test as app pool user and works - so I *think* I can discount user permissions.

Comment: Can you run a network trace on both to see if they are both using the same security ntlm vs Kerberos (try wireshark)